# Unable to install Snap-Store on Rpi-4b

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, raspbian-buster

I have had a problem with snap-store app on my raspberry pi. I installed it using these steps that I found on line in the command line:

`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install snapd`
`sudo reboot`
`sudo snap install core`
`sudo snap install snap-store`

After I did these steps I used the command "snap-store" and after it loads and I search a package, such as quake2, it does not load and if at all. The packages do not have any thumbnails off to the side instead, in their place, is a gear logo like so:

[image]

I have found no articles or videos on the subject on any sort of thing like that. I think I have a deeper problem and need to know the commands to uninstall snap-store so I can try installing it again. I think I did it in the wrong order and that might have caused the problem.

Another thing is if I click on a package (quake2 or any other) it looks kike this:

[image]Ideas?

Comment: I have found no videos on haw to fix snap-store also I can not load videos on the internet. (You'l see what I mean if you look at my other post about that)

Comment: Don't look for videos, look for articles.  Articles are a lot easier to understand, and they are sometimes more correct.  I have learned very little about raspberry pi from videos.  Articles are where the answers usually are.  Besides, the guy making the video usually learned how to do the process he is demonstrating by reading an article.  Which "other post about that" ?  Please include a link to it.

Comment: That's just the thing, I cant fined that either! I saw nothing.

Comment: Well see this.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+install+snap-store+on+raspberry+pi&t=raspberrypi&ia=web If none of these work,  I believe you may have another, deeper issue.

Comment: Nothing their is like my issue

Comment: I'm out of ideas. You have an issue that cannot be solved by the details you included.  Mabeye reinstall?

Comment: This is a rare kind of question where a screenshot of the problem could actually help. More to the point, I used the same commands on my system and they worked. Perhaps you should retry after flashing a fresh image.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing snap-store with pi-apps.
You install pi-apps by running `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash` in a terminal.  You also can directly get it from github here. https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps  After that, you need to launch pi-apps by running `pi-apps` in a teminal.  Then, click on the 'all apps' button on the home launcher.  Scroll down until you see the app called snap-store. [image]
Select it and click the "install" button.  (My gui looks different because I changed the theme.  It still is raspberry pi os.)

Comment: This only helped a little but did not fix the problem.

Comment: Why did you select it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Mistake thats all.

Comment: How is `pi-apps`  install different from the [official](https://snapcraft.io/install/snap-store/raspbian) one? To me it just sounds like adding possible issues with `pi-apps` to possible issues with `snap` itself.

Comment: Pi-Apps just runs the same terminal commands automatically that he would normally run manually.  It just does them in the right order; there is less room for a mistake on his part.