# How to remove snap-store from Rpi-4b Debian Buster?

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, raspbian-buster

I need to reinstall snap-store. I would be thankful if someone would tell me the commands to uninstall or reinstall it. You can see the reason why I need to install snap-store again here: [Unable to install Snap-Store on Rpi-4b](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133300/unable-to-install-snap-store-on-rpi-4b)   I looked it up  using DuckDuckGo
but found nothing their on how to uninstall, only to install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall snap-store by running `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`  That will reinstall.  If you have pi-apps, (I showed you how to install in this answer [Unable to install Snap-Store on Rpi-4b](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133300/unable-to-install-snap-store-on-rpi-4b/133311#133311) )  You can select the snap-store app (shown how in the answer) and click the "install" button.  It will ask you if you want to reinstall, say that you do, and it will reinstall snap-store.

Comment: When I did what you said it said this: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "snap-store", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install snap-store"

E: Unable to locate package snap-store

Comment: See latest edit.